# How to stop calling onConnected while activity resume(Android)

Tags: android, google-api-client, location-services

I have 2 activity with Activity1 and Activity2.
on Activity1->onCreate I use googleApliClient for location service

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    createLocationRequest();
}
```

and its working fine and call **onConnected** appropriately, my issue is when I move to Activity2 from Activity1 and come back to again to Activity1, it again call **onConnected** method, which I need to stop

so I try with below code on Activity1->onPause but it not help.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Where creating `GoogleApiClient` Object in onCreate,onStart or in onResume?

Comment: please put code of onResume method...

Comment: 1.GoogleApiClient object is initialized in onCreate
2.onResume method is not within activity

Answer (score 0):

Activities in Android in its own lifecycle does NOT have OnConnected callback.

The Activity class provides a core set of six callbacks: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy().

Follow the diagram below:
[image]

Please refer to: [The activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Updated following sugestion of: [WhatsThePoint User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7147233/whatsthepoint)

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)